# What are the responsibilities of a class constructor in python?

Tags: python, constructor, typechecking, ooad, duck-typing

I am currently studying some classic Object Orientation, and have read in some book (can't remember which one right now) that

> "The role of a constructor is to assure that new class instances are returned (by the constructor) in a valid state"

Since python uses duck typing, I wonder, for example, how can I prevent my object of receiving wrong or invalid arguments without explicit type checking, and also if that would leave the risk of taking an invalid instance further inside the programs, possibly causing errors later than would be the desired.

Comment: I think this is gonna get closed , however my 2c is that it should result in a correct intial state ..., however in python it is perfectly acceptable to just assign it to some class variables and raise an error when they actually try to use the class variables ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley you say "perfectly acceptable", but I would like to understand: acceptable based on what? Thanks

Comment: based on use-age in large, publicly accepted libraries ... really you've hit on the crux of why this will probably be closed is it basically boils down to an opinion based question

Comment: Generating a valid object almost certainly means calling your parent class's constructor, as well, but Python doesn't enforce this.

Answer (score 1):

That statement about returning an object in a valid state is broadly true, I suppose.

Basically, the constructor should setup the members of your class the way you wish based on the arguments that were passed in, similar to other languages.

It is **possible** to do type checking in Python via `isinstance`, although often times it's really not needed nor desired.

Really, with `duck typing`, the general procedure would be to write the code, including the constructor, as if the object `is a duck`. That is, that is has the methods and behaviors that you are expecting. If an object is passed in that doesn't have a particular method, say, that will raise a runtime exception.

Also, keep in mind the `__enter` and `__exit__` functions, which are used with the `with` paradigm. This can help clean up resources and is a response to the otherwise necessary `try/except/finally` blocks.